# How do I fix this paint rip?

Tags: repair, walls, painting, paint, primer

Accidentally ripped a piece of paint off the wall when trying to hang something up and now need to fix it ASAP. I have the sample to color match but I don’t quite know what to do to patch this… The edges are peeling and theres a few bubbles forming around the area. I don’t have any tools around so I’d have to start from scratch… Any advice?

[image: Ripped surface of painted wall]

Comment: Usually would say that is a sign of a bad paint job.  Will need to remove all loose paint, sand to feather edges, remove all dirt/dust/grease, then repaint.  Might be a good idea to get a small can/bottle of primer to go with the paint.

Comment: @crip659 how do i remove the loose paint?

Comment: Paint that is loose will come off easy, even with fingernails.  A plastic or metal paint scraper is the usual way.  Stop when paint sticks on the wall.  Do have a bad feeling it might be far away.

Comment: @crip659 thanks. And what should i do about the bubbles? they’re a bit far away too, am inexperienced so don’t want to have to paint the entire wall…

Comment: Can cut them out and repaint them, but usually with a bad paint job, the only good fix is repainting the wall by removing any and all loose paint.  Might get lucky and those are the only bad spots.  I don't mind painting, it is the preparation I hate.

Comment: @crip659 thanks for the tips… do you think it’d be ok to use a small regular paintbrush (like for art or something) or do i need to get a special one?

Comment: Would like one about an inch wide, but the size does not matter much except for amount of time it takes.  So far you are doing small sections.

Comment: @crip659 that makes sense… do you think it will be a difficult task to repair?

Comment: Is that on backer board? I can’t make out the substrate, makes a difference on the steps forward.

Comment: @EdBeal not 100% sure but i think that it might be

Comment: Is this your own home or are you renting? If you're renting, the landlord _might_ fix it if it's an overall bad paint job. OTOH, if you're renting, the landlord might charge you for a full repaint if he assumes you've damaged it...

Comment: Hang a picture over it.

Comment: @SteveWellens like this, but wasn't that the original cause of the problem :) So needs more pictures or a wall sized print....